# Leaflet.draw a circle error: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I use leaflet.draw for creating shapes(geozone) in the map and when i draw a circle, i'm getting this error [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zNjN.png) since a circle has no length and i'm also getting this error when i put **editable: true** in the shapeOptions:

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click", ".btnCircleDraw",function(){
        circleDrawer = new L.Draw.Circle(map, {

            shapeOptions: {
                color: color,
                fillOpacity: opacity,
                fillColor: color,
                stroke: color,
                opacity: opacity,
                editable: true
            }
        });     
    map.on('draw:created', drawCreated);
    circleDrawer.enable();

    });
```

I have this function drawCreated:

```
function drawCreated(e) {
        type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
        layer.addTo(drawnItems);
        console.log(type, ' drawn', layer);

        layer.on("edit", function(event) {
            var content = "";
            if (type === "circle") {
                //content = 'Circle with : <ul><li> Radius : ' + layer.getRadius() + '</li>'+
                //'<li> Center : ' + layer.getLatLng() + ' </li></ul>';
                var lngLat = layer.getLatLng();
                console.log("new: ", lngLat);
            }
        });

        if (type === 'circle') {
            var theCenterPt = layer.getLatLng();

            var theRadius = layer.getRadius();

            points['lng'] = theCenterPt.lng;
            points['lat'] = theCenterPt.lat;
            points['radius'] = theRadius;

            console.log(points);

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

        }
}
```

is there a solution or alternative for this problem?